# Regular Expressions C++ remove all non-alphabetic characters

Tags: replace

so I've been working on trying to solve some of the ACM-ICPC Archive files that require knowledge of a data structures, and complicated logic.

Anyways, the thing that's killing my programs ability to complete the task is this. I'm trying to parse a string. stripping it of all non-alphabetic characters.
For example, Abcd.::: will produce "Abcd    ", which replaces all the strings non-alphabetic characters with spaces.

I was using a switch statement covering the various punctuation marks, and swapping that position with a blank space. But that appears to be ineffective as I don't want to hard code all the values.

Is there a good regular expression that I can use to solve this problem? The reference material on regular expressions is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro try this regular expression if it works doesnt forget to qualify my answer

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

This only admits letters